How to create a decorator for a FastAPI route that is able to capture the path param value?
I have a FastAPI route like so:
@router.put("/{workflowID}", response_model=WorkflowResponse)
async def update_workflow_endpoint(
    workflowID: int, 
    workflow: WorkflowUpdateRequest, 
    db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)
):
    ... // Remaining code

I want to write a decorator which gets the path parameter workflowID, like so:
@allowed_perm('WF_ADMIN', {workflowID})

So it gets two parameters - a string WF_ADMIN and the value of workflowID path param.
For ex: if the API was called like so /5, then I want the decorator to internally get the value of 5.
How can this be done? I'm trying to build my permission module, and although I know this can be done using dependencies, I wanted to know if the same can be done via decorators.

I think you can pass workflowID as a string to your decorator (e. g. @allowed_perm('WF_ADMIN', path_param_name='workflowID' ). And then retrieve its value as request.path_parameters.get(path_param_name)

Yes, you can achieve it in following way:
from functools import wraps
from fastapi import HTTPException

def allowed_perm(role: str, param_name: str):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
            workflowID =kwargs.get(param_name)
            if workflowID is None:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="ERROR")
            
            if role != "WF_ADMIN":
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403,detail="Permision denied")
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@router.put("/{workflowID}", response_model=WorkflowResponse)
@allowed_perm('WF_ADMIN', 'workflowID')
async def update_workflow_endpoint(
    workflowID: int, 
    workflow: WorkflowUpdateRequest, 
    db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db),
):
    ...

